# How can I grayscale a canvas image in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, grayscale, imagedata

I have an image inside of an HTML5 canvas with the size of 28x28 pixels. I get the imageData of the canvas as an array of RGBA (red, green, blue, alpha) values using this code:

```
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 28, 28);
```

Now I want to grayscale the image, so that I get an array of 784 values (28x28 pixels) where each pixel has one value (instead of four).

I've found a lot of different formulas for grayscaling, some are multiplying the rgb values, some are just calculating the average - I really don't know which of them to use...

I'm also stuck at getting 784 values - it's always 3136 (because of the 4 channels)...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, there are multiple formulas, and you need to choose one. There is no single true formula.

Comment: Alright thx, but how can I get an array of 784 values after grayscaling an array with four values for each pixel?

Comment: In your four loop, just have two counters - one `i += 1`, one `j += 4` on every iteration.

Comment: Perfect! A for loop with two counters works just fine (idk why I didn't come up with this myself) - thank you!

Comment: That is not what OP is after, and hence not an answer to the body of this question, but for the title, note that CSS filters have been added to Canvas2D API, and that in supporting browsers, you can achieve a grayscale effect by simply setting the context's filter to `"grayscale(100%)"` before drawing the canvas over itself with a "copy" globalCompositeOperation mode.

Answer (score 17):

The main idea is to have the same value for the red green and blue component of the color. For this you need to calculate the lightness of every pixel. There are several ways to calculate the lightness. This is one of them.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let canvas = document.getElementById("c");

  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = 50;
  canvas.height = 50;

  let srcImg = document.getElementById("sof");
  ctx.drawImage(srcImg, 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  let imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  let pixels = imgData.data;
  for (var i = 0; i < pixels.length; i += 4) {

    let lightness = parseInt((pixels[i] + pixels[i + 1] + pixels[i + 2]) / 3);

    pixels[i] = lightness;
    pixels[i + 1] = lightness;
    pixels[i + 2] = lightness;
  }
  ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
  id="sof" />
```

*UPDATE:*
**Alternative `lightness` Calculations:**

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Luma_coding_in_video_systems) (Luma):
  `let lightness = parseInt(pixels[i]*.299 + pixels[i + 1]*.587 + pixels[i + 2]*.114);`
- elsewhere (source unknown):
  `let lightness = parseInt(3*pixels[i] + 4*pixels[i + 1] + pixels[i + 2] >>> 3);`
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Colourimetric_(perceptual_luminance-preserving)_conversion_to_greyscale) (Linear Luminance):
  `let lightness = 0.2126 * pixels[i] + 0.715 * pixels[i+1] + 0.0722 * pixels[i+2];`

Answer (score 12):

You can directly set a filter to the rendering context. It will be simpler than calculate every pixel color.

For this you should use `ctx.filter = 'grayscale(1)';`

```js
const img = document.querySelector('img');
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

img.onload = function() {
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  ctx.filter = 'grayscale(1)';
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
/>
```

Comment: Not Safari :(
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter

Comment: !#$%& Safari!!! 

Comment: There is already a PR for this https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/pull/3793, perhaps it will be there soon